# (PYTHON) Problemas con el valor devuelto

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles

Lo que intento hacer es una bucle que ordene un diccionario de mayor a menor según los valores de cada clave, y que a lo ultimo me imprima el conjunto calve-valor con el valor mas alto. Pero el problema es que no se como hacerlo, solo me devuelve el valor pero no la clave. Agradezco mucho la ayuda =)

```
 histograma:{'stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za': 1, 'paulaboscolo@hotmail.com': 10, 
 'louis@media.berkeley.edu': 1, 'zqian@umich.edu': 4, 'rjlowe@iupui.edu': 2, 'cwen@iupui.edu': 
  2, 'gsilver@umich.edu': 3, 'wagnermr@iupui.edu': 1, 'antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk': 1, 
 'gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com': 1, 'david.horwitz@uct.ac.za': 4}
 
 mayor=None
 for valor in histograma.values():
     if mayor is None or valor>mayor:
         mayor=valor
 print(mayor)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres obtener ambos valores entonces el método `items` resulta conveniente

```py
histograma={'stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za': 1, 'paulaboscolo@hotmail.com': 10, 
 'louis@media.berkeley.edu': 1, 'zqian@umich.edu': 4, 'rjlowe@iupui.edu': 2, 'cwen@iupui.edu': 
  2, 'gsilver@umich.edu': 3, 'wagnermr@iupui.edu': 1, 'antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk': 1, 
 'gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com': 1, 'david.horwitz@uct.ac.za': 4}
 
mayor=None
for clave,valor in histograma.items():
    if mayor is None or valor>mayor[1]:
        mayor=clave,valor
print(mayor)
```

Las únicas modificaciones es descomponer en `clave, valor` lo devuelto por `items` (devuelve una tupla `(key, value)`) y evaluar el segundo elemento de la variable mayor (`mayor[1]`) ya que ahora es una tupla